# Not able to generate aggregate csv file in Jmeter

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

In my application i am not able to create the aggregate file in my test? Below is the error iam facing, Any plugin i need to add?

ERROR: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jorphan.util.JOrphanUtils.closeQuietly(Ljava/io/Closeable;)V

*** Problem's technical details go below ***

Home directory was detected as: /prod/products/Performance_Testing/apache-jmeter-2.11/lib/ext
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jorphan.util.JOrphanUtils.closeQuietly(Ljava/io/Closeable;)V
        at org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(JMeterUtils.java:198)
        at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.initializeProperties(PluginsCMDWorker.java:95)
        at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.prepareJMeterEnv(PluginsCMDWorker.java:85)
        at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.(PluginsCMDWorker.java:55)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.ReporterTool.processParams(ReporterTool.java:66)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:63)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

## at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:174)

/prod/products/Performance_Testing/Application/Batch/../Results/1496905397Filters_ByPerson_PeopleSideA_1/Report/1496905686911/aggregate_00.csv (No such file or directory)
IOException: processing requests

Comment: what's your jmeter version?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) and [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) version mismatch

1. Upgrade to [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32)  (or whatever version will be the latest by that time), you can get it from [JMeter Downloads page](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)
2. Install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
3. Install plugins you require via the JMeter Plugins Manager

If the problem still persists report the problem via [JMeter Plugins Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins)

Comment: But i am using 3.12 version, if i need to upgrade my sciprt means it will take more time,because u know controllers are upgraded, so if i upgrade means it kind of recreating the script

Comment: can we get 3.12 plugins?